# javascript/jQuery - finding the difference of 2 complex arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm building an `autocomplete` but it's getting a little bit complex. When the source is built, I have 2 arrays: `availableTags` and `usedTags`. The user can select multiple tags for each list. I have this all working great as far as using simple arrays and splicing but once I add in additional fields such as id and other values, the array becomes complex so splicing and comparing isn't as easy. I'm wondering what I don't know that could be useful here instead of writing some unnecessarily large function to accomplish these tasks. I've searched but a lot of what I'm finding doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

[Here's a fiddle of it working with the simple arrays](https://jsfiddle.net/b3tac0d3/p4u7h1e0/) - I'm trying to accomplish this while adding additional fields.

Thanks!

**here's an example of what the arrays should look like - they might even have more fields**

```
var tarr = [
    {name: "jimmy", id: "1"},
    {name: "barbie", id: "2"}
];

var used = [
    {name: "jimmy", id: "1"}
];
```

**currently, my arrays in the working function just look like this**

```
var availableTags = [
    "jimmy",
    "anthony",
    "alonzo",
    "annabelle",
    "dylan",
    "barbie"
];
var usedTags = [];
```

**this is how I compare the difference of two simple arrays**

```
$(availableTags).not(usedTags).get()
```

**this is how I remove data from the simple arrays**

```
//re-add a value to the array for autocomplete if it's been removed from the added list
function readd2Array(inp){
    usedTags.splice($.inArray(inp, usedTags), 1);
}
```

So if I wanted to search the index of the more complex array, find data and remove, how would I do it? Also, if I wanted to compare the two arrays for unique values, how would I do that?

Comment: have you had a look at underscore.js ?

Comment: I have not...I feel like I should though :) I'll check it out. Anywhere in particular I should start?

Comment: If you populated `availableTags` with corresponding index integers wouldn't that make it easier? `var availableTags = [0, 4, 5]` or `[ tarr[2], tarr[6] ]` for instance.

Comment: @TheAngryDev - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-cozy-with-underscorejs--net-24581

Comment: @Daniel_L - I've been working on this so long that I think something this simple may have very well escaped me....I'm going to try it out and see if I can get it working. Thank you!